# Postman 401 Unauthorized using Ocelot

Tags: postman

I am implementing an Ocelot gateway.  When I make the API call using my browser to http://localhost:5009/api/values, I get a valid json response back.  However when I make the same request through Postman I get a 401 Unauthorized response.  Any ideas if there is a setting in Postman I need to change or something else.

Answer (score 0):

That is, the client must authenticate itself to get the requested response.
Most likely you have forgotten to put your token to the Header in Postman to be authenticated for the server in order to get a response.

Comment: also...make sure the token you submit in Postman is actually correct. I also got 401 Unauthorized back because the token had one character too much. Probably a copy paste error...